# Colored Background Stops at Bottom of Page, Not Content, Using Flex Layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a layout in which the background color extends to the height of the browser, but not the height of the content.

Starting with this JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/EvilClosetMonkey/g2Hmf/

I get a layout in the image below. The height of the 3-columns is the browser (or frame, in the case of JSFiddle), plus the height of the "header" row, plus the height of the "breadcrumb" row. This results in a little bit of scroll, but not much.

[image]

In this case the contents do not fill the full height, but I still wish the color to reach the bottom of the browser space. The trouble comes up if I add content to one of the columns. In this case, the background color still stops where it did before, but the content continues!

JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/EvilClosetMonkey/g2Hmf/1/

[image]

**How can I get my background color to consume the height of *content*, when it reaches past the browser height, not just the browser height?**

Variations of `height: 100%` on the columns have not yielded success. I've also tried putting all contents into the `flex` layout (not just the columns), but that did not create any different results.

HTML and CSS blocks below, for reference without visiting JSFiddle:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="crumbs">Breadcrumb</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="navigation">Nav</div>
    <div id="workspace">Contents</div>
    <div id="inspector">Info</div>
</div>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
    background-color: red;
}

#crumbs {
    background-color: blue;
}

#navigation {
    background-color: green;

    -webkit-box-flex: 0 0 240px;
    -moz-box-flex: 0 0 240px;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 240px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 240px;
    flex: 0 0 240px;
}

#workspace {
    background-color: orange;

    -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -moz-box-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#inspector {
    background-color: yellow;

    -webkit-box-flex: 0 0 240px;
    -moz-box-flex: 0 0 240px;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 240px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 240px;
    flex: 0 0 240px;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?
http://fiddle.jshell.net/g2Hmf/4/

This fix uses `#header` and `#crumbs` `height` and `margin-top` for `#content`.

I also added `#wrapper`.

Comment: It appears to be even simpler than that! I took your fiddle and found that just adding the `min-height` on `<div id="content">` seemed to do the trick. I'm still playing with it to be sure, but looks like that was all that is required. http://fiddle.jshell.net/EvilClosetMonkey/g2Hmf/5/

Answer (score 1):

Just remove height:100% from body :) so it expands to all available space  instead of expanding to only 100% of visible screen. Maybe that 100% thing is for divs and tables. Body is already everywhere. But limiting it to 100% of visible screen can be useful for some other sites.

Above is for the second link you gave in your question.

Comment: But doing that on the [first JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/EvilClosetMonkey/g2Hmf/) will cause the columns to shrink up; leaving whitespace below. Is a way I can expend the background-color if the contents don't fill the screen, while still stretching it to consume additional content beyond the `body` height?

Comment: I also just noticed the language in my question somewhat contradicts the above comment. I'll adjust my question - apologies for the confusion!

Comment: Ive meant the second link of yours.

Comment: Totally makes sense on why that is happening there, but I can't guarantee the contents will always reach the bottom. In that case I'd still like the color to reach the bottom of the screen. I'll tinker with more `height` parameters and see if there isn't some magic to unfold.

Comment: You can try on IETester for IE compatibility testing and can try different screen modes with browserstack.com. Chrome is smart enough for this things.